# Installed Cocoapods into existing project - Error in project explorer

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

[image]

I installed CocoaPods on an existing project and am having trouble compiling. Going through possible issues one by one, and one of them is this red link in the project explorer. What does this mean and is it something that can cause issue?

Using xcode 5.0.2.

---

EDIT

This might or might not be related. I updated my podfile to include the line:

```
xcodeproj `WSPhoto`
```

Because there are multiple projects and I wanted to make sure cocoapods linked with the main one. Before including this line, `pod install` worked without error. With this line, I get the following error:

```
[!] Unable to find the Xcode project `WSPhoto/.xcodeproj.xcodeproj` for the target `Pods`.
```

---

EDIT 2

So I now have Cocoapods working, even though the `container:WSPhoto.xcodeproj` entry is still in the project explorer window.

I did two things:

1. `xcodeproj WSPhoto` was syntactically wrong. I need to use regular apostrophes like so:

   xcodeproj 'WSPhoto'
2. I changed the 'Build Active Architectures Only' option for the Pods project to NO.

The Pods libraries are now linked and the project builds, so it seems like the `container:WSPhoto.xcodeproj` error was unrelated to the bigger issue.